# Windows Bluetooth Handsfree audio disappears after few minutes of audio

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I bought a Bluetooth earphone to use during my meetings. When I connect to my laptop, I can see there are two options. One is for "Stereo" and the other is "Handsfree". If I select the "Stereo" option, I do not get any interruption while hearing music or watching YouTube. But when I need to select the "Handfree" option to talk to my colleagues over Skype or Google Hangout, the audio disappears after a few minutes. I could see the audio bar moving but I cannot hear any audio. So whenever I select "Stereo" mode and reselect "Handsfree" mode, the audio comes back.

What could possibly be the reason to drop audio after a few minutes later whenever I am using the "Handsfree" mode? And how can I stop this from happening again?

Comment: I'm also curious, although the handsfree option seems useless because of its much worse quality, I never use it and use pavucontrol to select the right output.

Comment: yea although it has worse quality, I cannot use my headset's built-in mic without the hands-free option selected.